# Change UIImage render mode at runtime

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

In an app I am working on I have some UIImageViews that may (or may not) need to be customised. How can I change the rendering mode of an image that was loaded as original to template at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can init a `UIImage` from another `cgImage`, then you can render it as you need

**ExampleCode**

```
let originalImage = UIImage(named: "TimeClock2Filled")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
if let original = originalImage?.cgImage {
    let image2 = UIImage(cgImage: original).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
}
```

**Example code Objective-C**

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TimeClock2Filled"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
if(image.CGImage != nil) {
    UIImage * image2 = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
}
```

this works just fine was tested

Comment: could you add objective-c answer too? the project is in obj-c

Comment: @user426132 please can you kindly provide some feedback about the answer?

Comment: Ok, wow.. the coloring works BUT now the image is not scalling to fit the imageview and is too large ... I tryed setting the content mode to aspectFit but it didn't work

Comment: weird @user426132 because should'n change size or form, can you test your image normally without any modification and see what happens?, at least not in my test, there is no change only color

Comment: I added scale to the initialization and it now works